# Sending Rstudio view() content to different pane

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Using Rstudio, I am attempting to display a dataFrame using the View() command.  The command automatically sends the output to the 'Source' quadrant.

Is there any way to send it instead to either the "Workspace" quandrant or the "Files,Plots..." quadrant?
Here is my code:

```
qRows <- data.frame( RowQuery = character(0), "BackTest P&L" = character(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
qRows[nrow(qRows) + 1, ] <- c("@sp500(vwpc) | rsi(30) | qcume",  "12%")
View(qRows)
```

Comment: The location of the `View` table can be set in RStudio's global preferences, under Pane Layout, where you can check the "Viewer" box in whichever quadrant you prefer. This is unrelated to the R or its `data.frame` class. You can verify this by starting R in a terminal and running the same code; R will open a new window to show the data viewer. Rstudio just captures that window behind the scenes and instead pops it in the quadrant set in preferences.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that option, but setting it to either the "Workspace" or "Files,Plots.." quadrant does not make a difference.  Output from View() is still sent to the "Source" quadrant.   For plot and chart commands, output is sent to the quadrant with the "Viewer", but not true for the View command.

Comment: That "Viewer" tab is not the same as the data viewer.  It is a viewer for local web content.  See here for more on that: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane

Answer (score 21, accepted):

to display a data frame in the "Files,Plots..." quadrant (Viewer) use the DT package:

```R
if (!require("DT")) devtools::install_github("rstudio/DT")
datatable(qRows)
```

all those commands will open it in a separate window:

1. new window where you can edit data; whet it open you can't code in console and run the code from code editor; after closing window all info from table will be displayed into console

```R
edit(qRows)
```

2. like in point 1, but without displaying info into console after closing the window

```R
invisible(edit(qRows))
```

or

```R
data.entry(qRows)
```

3. like in point 2, but you can't edit info into this window and you can use the console

```R
utils::View(qRows)
```

R Package googleVis can send your table to browser:

```R
if (!require("googleVis")) devtools::install_github("rstudio/googleVis")
plot(gvisTable(qRows))
```

knitr/RMarkdown can send your dataframe to html/pdf/doc/slides etc; you will create a beautiful table in console or markdown issued file with:

```R
if (!require("knitr")) devtools::install_github("rstudio/knitr")
knitr::kable(qRows)
```

Comment: @katherine, this answer is a bit sparse.  Can you elaborate your steps a bit, making it clear what is code and what is your explanation?  there is lots of formatting available.